# problem with counter

Tags: c

I have a simple program in mind where it reads the input first name and last name respectively and shows the number of characters present in each, but I am getting both the  values as 5.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int count=0;
    int counter=0;
    printf("enter your  first name");
    scanf("%s",fname);
    printf("enter your last name");
    scanf("%s",lname);

    while((fname[count]>0) && (lname[counter]>0))
    { 
        count++;
        counter++;
    }
    printf("the no of char in ur fname  are %d ",count);
    printf(" the no of char in ur lname are %d ",counter);
}
```

Any advice would be of great help.

Comment: Note that '`void main()`' is at best non-standard and is typically wrong.  You should probably specify how long the name arrays in the `scanf()` formats (`"%19s"`) to prevent overlong names causing crashes.  You should print a newline at the end of the output (probably at the end of each of the last two `printf()` statements.  If you are using a C99 compiler, omitting `return 0;` from the end of the program is 'OK' (he says with gritted teeth), but it is better to be explicit and return the correct status. You should probably make the two `printf()` statements more symmetric (no stray blanks).

Comment: thanks for helping would truly love to implement your suggestions and a very thanks again

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - it's not against the standard if the implementation specifies it as a supported `main` signature. From the C99 standard (5.1.2.2.1): "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner"

Comment: @detly: yes - that's basically what I said.  The standard says the return type is "int" and allows for implementation-defined alternatives which are not standard.  Hence the caveat 'and is typically wrong'.

Comment: @detly: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) says: 'Alternatively, the main and wmain functions can be declared as returning void (no return value). If you declare main or wmain as returning void, you cannot return an exit code to the parent process or operating system by using a return statement. To return an exit code when main or wmain is declared as void, you must use the exit function.' It is not clear to me what happens (what exit code is returned to the parent or o/s) when a program with `void main()` does exit - and the MS web site is silent too.

Comment: @detly: Interestingly, MS does not prescribe the two-argument version of `main()` that the C and C++ standards require. It only prescribes a three argument form where the third argument is 'char **envp', a pointer to a list of environment variables. The C++ standard says "It [the main function] shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation defined", and requires the same two signatures as the C standard.  So a 'void main()' is directly not allowed by the C++ standard, though there's nothing it can do to stop a non-standard implementation allowing alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

You're counting both in the same loop. Split it into two loops.

Comment: thanks for your help really helpful so i went ahead and made two loops of counter such as

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, you are incrementing both counters at the same time - you need to split the counting into two separate loops (one for each string)

Try this instead:

```
while(fname[count] > 0)
{ 
    fnameCount++;
}

while(lname[count] > 0)
{ 
    lnameCount++;
}

printf("the no of characters in your first name is %d ", fnameCount);
printf("the no of characters in your last name is %d ", lnameCount);
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply to my question and your suggestion really worked thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variables `count` and `counter` both end at the same time and will have the same value. Your if condition says to increment the two counters as long as **either** of the two char arrays have not yet ended. The moment you reach the end of one of the two char arrays, both counter variables are set to the length of the shorter array.

You need to have two `for` loops, one for each char array.

Comment: thanks for replyin but do i have to split the counter or the printf statements or both ..?

Comment: @jhonny: Read Kragen's answer to see what I meant.